# Website Scraping with BeautifulSoup : TypeError: 'ResultSet'

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, resultset

I used the following code below,unfortunately I get an error :-(

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

price = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})(0).find()
print(price)
```

Do you know why it says:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4a9fd9081b7f> in <module>
      8 #print(soup)
      9 
---> 10 price = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})(0).find()
     11 print(price)

TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable
```

Is there anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup's `find_all` method returns a list (a resultset). You need to treat it as a list and print results one by one. That subsequent `find()` at the end - I cannot explain it from my knowledge of bs4. Also, if you want to refer to an element in a list by index, you need to use square brackets, like so: `my_list[0]`. Also, your class is incomplete.

Here is a correct way of dealing with a list in your scenario (although that list has just one element):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
# print(soup)
prices = soup.select('div[class ^= "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"]')
print(len(prices))
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
1
144.11-1.99 (-1.36%)As of  11:20AM EDT. Market open.  
                Advertisement
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found here: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/